# Require sls by its ID Declaration

Tags: salt-stack

I have two state files:

- `php/init.sls`
- `php-fpm.sls`

`php/init.sls` installs the package `php53u`

I'm trying to get `php-fpm.sls` to require `php` as that is how I declare it inside `php/init.sls`, however it only works if I require the `pkg: php53u` and not `sls: php`

Contents of `php/init.sh`:

```
php:
  pkg:
    - name: php53u
    - installed
```

Contents of `php-fpm.sls` (using `pkg` where it works):

```
include:
  - nginx
  - php

php-fpm:
  pkg:
    - name: php53u-fpm
    - installed
  service:
    - running
    - enable: True
    - require:
      - pkg: php53u-fpm
      - pkg: php53u

extend:
  nginx:
    file:
      - name: /etc/nginx/php-fpm
      - source: salt://nginx/src/etc/nginx/php-fpm
      - managed
      - template: jinja
```

(note that this has extra stuff about `nginx` that currently isn't a `require` though it should be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correctly including the php sls file. You just need to set your require like this:

```
- pkg: php
```

Here's an example that should work:

```
php-fpm:
  pkg:
    - name: php53u-fpm
    - installed
    - require:
      - pkg: php
  service:
    - running
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - pkg: php53u-fpm
      - pkg: php
```

Notice that I also added the require to the pkg stanza to make sure that the php package is installed before the php53u-fpm package.

I also changed the "require" under the service stanza to a "watch". A "watch" acts as a "require", but also will restart the service if the "watched" pkg changes. So if there's a package upgrade it will restart the service automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal, in the require list, you need to use ID Declaration (http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/highstate.html#term-id-declaration).

The module php/init.sls contains only one ID Declaration : {pkg: php53u}. ID Declaration is composed of state name (pkg) and component name (php53u).

You can't require an entire module in salt, but in the last versions, modules will be executed in order of declaration, so the php module should be executed before the php-fm one. Salt will respect require requisite references in any cases.

Vocabulary in salt-stack could be a little difficult for beginners, here is a page which can helps you : http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/highstate.html.

Comment: The example in http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/highstate.html#large-example under `# multiple states for single id` seems to reference what I've listed as `php` as the `ID Declaration` though. Further, the example in http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/highstate.html#requisite-reference under `Name declaration` for `mywebsite` and `apache` also seems to back me up.